# Python - Is there a way I can dynamically play with data in Excel file using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

What can I do to make this work ? This program executes successfully but shows this error
if (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
All it does is, selects Price that are greater than $500 and color codes the cells in the Excel.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx")
sh2 = wb1.active

for r in range(1,sh2.max_row+2):
    for c in range(1,sh2.max_column+1):
        if (sh2.cell(row=1, column=c).value) == "Price":
             if (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500:
                print(sh2.cell(r+1,c).value)
                sh2.cell(r+1, c).fill = PatternFill("solid","71FF35")
               

wb1.save("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx")
print("file Saved")
```

Comment: It looks like you're converting a cell to int which is null. Try something like: `if sh2.cell(r+1,c).value and (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500:`

Comment: I did not understand this part - Try something like: if sh2.cell(r+1,c).value and (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500: .... can you pls explain how the two parameters can be the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500:` - will throw an exception if `sh2.cell(r+1,c).value` is `None` (which is Pythons equivalent of null).

The value will most likely contains `None` because you're looping throw a rage of `sh2.max_row+2` (*you probably don't need the + 2*)

One solution to get around this issue is to always check value is not null by using `if sh2.cell(r+1,c).value and ...`. For example `if sh2.cell(r+1,c).value and (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500:`

Alternatively you can set a default of 0 using `or` operator. E.g: `if (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value or 0) > 500:`

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx")
sh2 = wb1.active

for r in range(1,sh2.max_row+2):
    for c in range(1,sh2.max_column+1):
        if (sh2.cell(row=1, column=c).value) == "Price":
             # Commented out line below to check not None and value is greater than 500.
             # if sh2.cell(r+1,c).value and (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value) > 500:
             # Code below will convert None to 0 and prevent exception.
             if (sh2.cell(r+1,c).value or 0) > 500:
                print(sh2.cell(r+1,c).value)
                sh2.cell(r+1, c).fill = PatternFill("solid","71FF35")
               

wb1.save("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx")
print("file Saved")
```